# GraalVM native image runtime exception: class is instantiated reflectively but was never registered

Tags: java, graalvm-native-image

I got this runtime exception when running the generated native image:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint$Transceiver[] is instantiated reflectively but was never registered.Register the class by adding "unsafeAllocated" for the class in reflect-config.json.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.SubstrateAllocationSnippets.arrayHubErrorStub(SubstrateAllocationSnippets.java:345)
        at com.mysys.common.util.Utilities$IndexingStore.register(Utilities.java:540)
        at com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint.transceive(MyClientEndpoint.java:188)
        at com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint.syncRunCtrlOperation(MyClientEndpoint.java:206)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ClientMgr.ctrlLogin(ClientMgr.java:395)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ClientMgr.login(ClientMgr.java:241)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ui.UIMgr.lambda$new$2(UIMgr.java:20)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ui.Tui.login(Tui.java:74)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ui.Tui.access$100(Tui.java:37)
        at com.mysys.myclient.ui.Tui$1.run(Tui.java:63)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
```

reflect-config.json (I tried all possible combinations and even put like bellow with non worked):

```
[
  {
    "name": "com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint$Transceiver",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "transceive",
        "parameterTypes": []
      }
    ],
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysys.common.util.Utilities$IndexingStore",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "register",
        "parameterTypes": []
      }
    ],
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint.Transceiver",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "transceive",
        "parameterTypes": []
      }
    ],
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  },
  {
    "name": "com.mysys.common.util.Utilities.IndexingStore",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "register",
        "parameterTypes": []
      }
    ],
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  }
]
```

Native image generation command line:

```
native-image -jar myclient-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar  \
 --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger \
 --initialize-at-build-time=io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory \
 --initialize-at-build-time=io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup \
 --initialize-at-build-time=io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory \
 --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.epoll.Native  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventArray  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueue  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventArray  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.kqueue.Native  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.Limits  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.Errors  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.IovArray  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.handler.ssl.BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.incubator.codec.quic.InsecureQuicTokenHandler  \
 --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.incubator.codec.quic.SecureRandomQuicConnectionIdGenerator \
 --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime \
 -H:IncludeResources="ssl/.*cert$" \
 -H:IncludeResources="images/.*png$" \
 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces \
 -H:Log=registerResource:3 \
 -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json
```

Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE'
Java version info: '17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08'
C compiler: gcc (redhat, x86_64, 8.5.0)
Garbage collector: Serial GC

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reflect-config.json worked:

```
[
  {
    "name": "com.mysys.myclient.net.MyClientEndpoint$Transceiver[]",
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  }
]
```

ref: https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/4284#issuecomment-1353709280